# Golang parse time.Duration

Tags: parsing, time, go, duration, iso8601

I would like to parse `time.Duration`. The duration is `"PT15M"` (string/bytes) and would like to convert it to a valid `time.Duration`.

---

If this were a `time.Time` thing, I would use:

`t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2013-06-05T14:10:43.678Z")`

But this doesn't exist (`ParseDuration` only takes one parameter):

`d, err := time.ParseDuration(time.RFC3339Nano, "PT15M")`

---

How can I parse this [ISO 8601 duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601?oldformat=true#Durations)?

Comment: From a quick google: https://github.com/ChannelMeter/iso8601duration

Comment: Nothing out-of-the-box?

Comment: No, nothing in the standard library. Why are you so concerned about using a library? It's not that big of a deal in Go, with no external dependencies tool needed and static binaries.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly "out of the box" but a regular expression does the job:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"
import "strconv"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ParseDuration("PT15M"))
    fmt.Println(ParseDuration("P12Y4MT15M"))
}

func ParseDuration(str string) time.Duration {
    durationRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`P(?P<years>\d+Y)?(?P<months>\d+M)?(?P<days>\d+D)?T?(?P<hours>\d+H)?(?P<minutes>\d+M)?(?P<seconds>\d+S)?`)
    matches := durationRegex.FindStringSubmatch(str)

    years := ParseInt64(matches[1])
    months := ParseInt64(matches[2])
    days := ParseInt64(matches[3])
    hours := ParseInt64(matches[4])
    minutes := ParseInt64(matches[5])
    seconds := ParseInt64(matches[6])

    hour := int64(time.Hour)
    minute := int64(time.Minute)
    second := int64(time.Second)
    return time.Duration(years*24*365*hour + months*30*24*hour + days*24*hour + hours*hour + minutes*minute + seconds*second)
}

func ParseInt64(value string) int64 {
    if len(value) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    parsed, err := strconv.Atoi(value[:len(value)-1])
    if err != nil {
        return 0
    }
    return int64(parsed)
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple but it doesn't support fractional times. The smallest value used may also have a decimal fraction, as in "P0.5Y" to indicate half a year. This decimal fraction may be specified with either a comma or a full stop, as in "P0,5Y" or "P0.5Y". It is common for milliseconds to be represented as PT0.032S.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that handles fractional time units like `PT3.001S`.

```
var durationRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`P([\d\.]+Y)?([\d\.]+M)?([\d\.]+D)?T?([\d\.]+H)?([\d\.]+M)?([\d\.]+?S)?`)

// ParseDuration converts a ISO8601 duration into a time.Duration
func ParseDuration(str string) time.Duration {
   matches := durationRegex.FindStringSubmatch(str)

   years := parseDurationPart(matches[1], time.Hour*24*365)
   months := parseDurationPart(matches[2], time.Hour*24*30)
   days := parseDurationPart(matches[3], time.Hour*24)
   hours := parseDurationPart(matches[4], time.Hour)
   minutes := parseDurationPart(matches[5], time.Second*60)
   seconds := parseDurationPart(matches[6], time.Second)

   return time.Duration(years + months + days + hours + minutes + seconds)
}

func parseDurationPart(value string, unit time.Duration) time.Duration {
   if len(value) != 0 {
       if parsed, err := strconv.ParseFloat(value[:len(value)-1], 64); err == nil {
           return time.Duration(float64(unit) * parsed)
       }
   }
   return 0
}
```

Comment: There is a problem here if you are planning on adding the duration to a time since the meaning of Year and Month is dependent on the actual time you are adding the duration to. For example, if you add a year that is a leap year, or a month that doesn't have 30 days, you will get the wrong answer.